# Prevent an object to be casted to any but one type C++

Tags: c++, casting

I defined this class:

```
template <class T>
class pure
{
public:
    pure(T const& attr) {
        this->attr = attr;
    }

    ~pure() {}

    T& operator=(T const& attr) {
        return attr;
    }

    operator T() {
        return this->attr;
    }

private:
    T attr;
};
```

This is a class that stores a value of type `T`. When I want to use an instance of it, I get the `attr` (by casting `pure` to `T`) instead of the instance (of `pure`) itself.

My goal here is to make a class that can't be casted to any type other than the type of `attr`, which is `T`.

Comment: If you don't your object being cast from `pure` to `T` don't offer a conversion operator for it.

Comment: No, I want that my pure cannot be casted to any type **other than T**

Comment: why is this a bad question?

Comment: It's not unanswered.

Comment: seven downvotes? could any of them give some kind of feedback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a C++11 capable compiler you could add e.g. the following member function:

```
template<typename U>
operator U() = delete;
```

That function is a generic casting operator, and marked as deleted (which is a new feature in C++11). Because it's marked as deleted, then casting to any other type than `T` will lead to a compiler error.

---

If you *don't* have a C++11 capable compiler, then you can add basically the same function declaration as a `private` function, and you will get another error:

```
private:
    template<typename U>
    operator U();
```

Comment: I have C++ 11 and your method worked very well, thanks a lot again ! I will mark your post as an answer ! Very good an simple, I like this delete keyword.