# Ambiguity with cout << and casts c++

Tags: c++, casting

For an exercice, I writed a little class in C++ **that cannot be casted to other types than the generic parameter T**:

```
template <class T>
class pure
{
public:

pure(T const& attr)
{
    this->attr = attr;
}

~pure()
{
}

T& operator=(T const& attr)
{
    return attr;
}

operator T()
{
    return attr;
}

template<typename U>
operator U() = delete;

private:
T attr;
};
```

And here is the main :

```
int main() 
{
pure<int> i = 15;

    //This won't compile, like I wanted
    //All the casts to other types than int won't compile
cout << (short)i;

    //BUT when I'm using mye pure object without a cast, I get a lot of   ambiguities errors
    cout << i;

system("PAUSE");
return 0; 
}
```

So, why the second cout doesn't work ? This should be work because I deleted all other possible casts than int. Thanks for help. Refrring to this may help to understand: [Prevent an object to be casted to any but one type C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431972/prevent-an-object-to-be-casted-to-any-but-one-type-c)

Comment: [Deleted functions participate in overload resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution).

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine if you overload the `<<` operator for `pure<T>`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class pure {
    T attr;

public:
    pure(T const& attr) {
        this->attr = attr;
    }

    T& operator=(T const& attr) {
        return attr;
    }

    operator T() {
        return attr;
    }

    template<typename U>
    operator U() = delete;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, pure<T> p) {
    os << static_cast<T>(p);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    pure<int> i = 15;

    //This won't compile, like I wanted
    //All the casts to other types than int won't compile
    cout << static_cast<short>(i);

    //Now works fine
    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, but I don't want to have to write tons of operators for resolve ambiguity on all operators ! Is there a way much easier ? Is exists a "wildcard" operator wich do an a static cast for each operator ?

Comment: Unforunately no, there is no wildcard operator. You might be able to make due with macros to implement the operators you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

See [Why do C++11-deleted functions participate in overload resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution) to understand why

```
 cout << i << endl;
```

doesn't work.

Workarounds:

1. Provide an appropriate `operator<<()` overload.
2. Remove the explicitly deleted cast operators.

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class pure
{
   public:
      operator T()
      {
         return 0;
      }

};

int main()
{
   pure<int> p;
   std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the goal of the class pure is to prevent to cast a pure object to another type than T. You are destructing all I wanted to do at beginning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431972/prevent-an-object-to-be-casted-to-any-but-one-type-c You also deleted my sugar initializer.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineJacob: Right, so option #1 is your only solution.

Comment: But, it's dumb ! I expressively deleted all other operator ! Why there is an ambiguity ?!

Comment: @Marc-AntoineJacob: This answer contains, prominently, a link to the explanation of why. Read it. _This is the purpose of `delete`_.

Comment: So no solution than write allll operators ?

Comment: @Marc-AntoineJacob, I don't think so.